# Detecting Application Pin State

Tags: winapi

In Windows 7 and up. You can right click and select "Pin icon to taskbar". If pinned I call thate "pinned" state. If it is not I call that "unpinned" state.

I was wondering if there was a way through WinAPI to detect if my application is pinned to the taskbar or not. Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you want to know this?

Comment: Whether it's pinned or not is a user preference. What possible use could you make of this information?

Comment: Just a curious observation: I think when we ask users "why?" in the comments it leads to XY haha. Anyways here's my take, I've been dealing a lot with `IPropertyStore` lately and came across this: `System.AppUserModel.StartPinOption` although the docs on this state ` pinned to the Start screen`, so this may not work on taskbar, the docs are here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj553605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Awesome question, it ended up helping me a ton for another situation I was in!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [no programmatic access](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/03/54760.aspx) to pinned shortcuts because people would just abuse them.

For your specific case the least hacky way is probably to look for yourself in

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar
```

Comment: He may also want to check the folders in `%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\ImplicitAppShortcuts`, also he will probably want to check the paths of the shortcut files there right? Wouldn't it be best to test the `System.AppUserModel.ID` of the shortcuts? Like test to see if it is of his app? Maybe I'm just working too much with `IPropertyStore` to suggest this haha.

Comment: @Noitidart We don't know if he has a System.AppUserModel.ID but yes, he would obviously have to check the shortcut targets...

Comment: Fantastic, this along with ImplicitAppShortcuts worked. Thanks fellahs.